# Inject inline svg into div tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, inline-svg

I'm working with an ecommerce platform and cannot install d3 or other svg libraries. For security reasons, the site won't let me manipulate iframes that have "external sources"—apparently, all iframes are external, but whatever.

So what I have resorted to is trying to inject an svg into a div tag. not sure why my code won't work. Do I need to append an svg  or something fancy? It's supposed to change the circle to red when pressed.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=inlinetest>
  <svg
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
     xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
     width="100mm"
     height="100mm"
     viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
     id="svg2"
     version="1.1"
     inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
     sodipodi:docname="drawing-2.svg">
    <defs
       id="defs4" />
    <sodipodi:namedview
       id="base"
       pagecolor="#ffffff"
       bordercolor="#666666"
       borderopacity="1.0"
       inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
       inkscape:pageshadow="2"
       inkscape:zoom="0.7"
       inkscape:cx="110.88456"
       inkscape:cy="710.05401"
       inkscape:document-units="px"
       inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
       showgrid="false"
       inkscape:window-width="250"
       inkscape:window-height="250"
       inkscape:window-x="-8"
       inkscape:window-y="-8"
       inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
    <metadata
       id="metadata7">
      <rdf:RDF>
        <cc:Work
           rdf:about="">
          <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
          <dc:type
             rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
          <dc:title></dc:title>
        </cc:Work>
      </rdf:RDF>
    </metadata>
    <g
       inkscape:label="Layer 1"
       inkscape:groupmode="layer"
       id="layer1">
      <circle
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
         id="path3336"
         cx="131.42857"
         cy="129.50507"
         r="131.42857" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</div>


</body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('inlinetest').innerHTML = "<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="100mm"
   height="100mm"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing-2.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.7"
     inkscape:cx="110.88456"
     inkscape:cy="710.05401"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="250"
     inkscape:window-height="250"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <circle
       style="fill:none;stroke:#FF0000;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="path3336"
       cx="131.42857"
       cy="129.50507"
       r="131.42857" />
  </g>
</svg>";
}

</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple problems here.  First of all, I'll mention that how you're doing this is highly inadvisable.  Replacing the entire SVG element with a string using innerHTML rather than just modifying a single property in the SVG, using onclick property, breaking out a string into all those lines.  A lot can go wrong.

First, to get your code at least functioning, you need to escape all the newline characters in your string assignment.  That can be done by just adding `\` to the end of every line that breaks the string.  Unfortunately, you also use double quote to enclose the string, while having double quotes in your string.  You'll need to escape those too.

Lastly, your `onclick` property won't work because at that point in the document, `myFunction` doesn't exist.  I've added it as an event listener using `addEventListener` instead.

While this "works", I would encourage you to instead update the individual elements in the SVG or add a class and use CSS to do it, but certainly don't replace the whole thing every time using a huge string to do so.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=inlinetest>
  <svg
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
     xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
     width="100mm"
     height="100mm"
     viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
     id="svg2"
     version="1.1"
     inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
     sodipodi:docname="drawing-2.svg">
    <defs
       id="defs4" />
    <sodipodi:namedview
       id="base"
       pagecolor="#ffffff"
       bordercolor="#666666"
       borderopacity="1.0"
       inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
       inkscape:pageshadow="2"
       inkscape:zoom="0.7"
       inkscape:cx="110.88456"
       inkscape:cy="710.05401"
       inkscape:document-units="px"
       inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
       showgrid="false"
       inkscape:window-width="250"
       inkscape:window-height="250"
       inkscape:window-x="-8"
       inkscape:window-y="-8"
       inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
    <metadata
       id="metadata7">
      <rdf:RDF>
        <cc:Work
           rdf:about="">
          <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
          <dc:type
             rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
          <dc:title></dc:title>
        </cc:Work>
      </rdf:RDF>
    </metadata>
    <g
       inkscape:label="Layer 1"
       inkscape:groupmode="layer"
       id="layer1">
      <circle
         style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
         id="path3336"
         cx="131.42857"
         cy="129.50507"
         r="131.42857" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<div>
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>
</div>


</body>
<script>
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
document.getElementById('inlinetest').innerHTML = "<svg\
   xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\"\
   xmlns:cc=\"http://creativecommons.org/ns#\"\
   xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\"\
   xmlns:svg=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"\
   xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"\
   xmlns:sodipodi=\"http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd\"\
   xmlns:inkscape=\"http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape\"\
   width=\"100mm\"\
   height=\"100mm\"\
   viewBox=\"0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047\"\
   id=\"svg2\"\
   version=\"1.1\"\
   inkscape:version=\"0.91 r13725\"\
   sodipodi:docname=\"drawing-2.svg\">\
  <defs\
     id=\"defs4\" />\
  <sodipodi:namedview\
     id=\"base\"\
     pagecolor=\"#ffffff\"\
     bordercolor=\"#666666\"\
     borderopacity=\"1.0\"\
     inkscape:pageopacity=\"0.0\"\
     inkscape:pageshadow=\"2\"\
     inkscape:zoom=\"0.7\"\
     inkscape:cx=\"110.88456\"\
     inkscape:cy=\"710.05401\"\
     inkscape:document-units=\"px\"\
     inkscape:current-layer=\"layer1\"\
     showgrid=\"false\"\
     inkscape:window-width=\"250\"\
     inkscape:window-height=\"250\"\
     inkscape:window-x=\"-8\"\
     inkscape:window-y=\"-8\"\
     inkscape:window-maximized=\"1\" />\
  <metadata\
     id=\"metadata7\">\
    <rdf:RDF>\
      <cc:Work\
         rdf:about=\"\">\
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>\
        <dc:type\
           rdf:resource=\"http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage\" />\
        <dc:title></dc:title>\
      </cc:Work>\
    </rdf:RDF>\
  </metadata>\
  <g\
     inkscape:label=\"Layer 1\"\
     inkscape:groupmode=\"layer\"\
     id=\"layer1\">\
    <circle\
       style=\"fill:none;stroke:#FF0000;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none\"\
       id=\"path3336\"\
       cx=\"131.42857\"\
       cy=\"129.50507\"\
       r=\"131.42857\" />\
  </g>\
</svg>";
});

</script>


</html>
```

Comment: awesome thanks man. i owuldnt have figured out ending all the lines in \

Comment: i really appreciate the help . i researched this for days and nobody i found did it like this. i simplified my sample code because as you said modifying the individual object would be much better but unfortunately i am adding 2  completely different svg files. again thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `<img src="XxX"/>` tag or use `<svg>`. More info here: [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/)

Comment: Not sure why there's a downvote.  I don't like the W3schools reference, but this is a viable method.  You would just have to base64 encode the svg (considering external sources are a no go).

Comment: @josephmarikle Images are not interactive so changing the circle to red on click won't be possible.

Comment: @RobertLongson OP's original scenario isn't interactive anyway.  Every time you click the button it blows away the existing SVG and replaces it entirely with a new SVG created by simply changing the `innerHTML` of the containing div.  It's a shade of difference to encode it as base64 and use an `img` tag.

Comment: @josephmariekle read the last sentence the op writes... It's supposed to change the circle to red when pressed.

Comment: @RobertLongson It would.  Right now, my snippet in the answer I provided just fixes a few errors in OP's original code.  All it does is nuke the original SVG and replace it with another SVG with an inline `stroke:#000000;` changed to `stroke:#FF0000;`.  The same exact thing could be accomplished using a base64 encoded string of the new SVG code.

Comment: @JosephMarikle that seems overkill compared to just updating the stroke colour of the existing element.

Comment: @RobertLongson I completely agree. :)